# Is there a way i can embed videos using the <embed> tag, that does allow fullscreen?

Tags: html

When i just use `<embed src="examplevideo.mp4">`, it does work ONLY on the webpage the fullscreen button is just greyed out and i can't click it. I've tried searching this, but i couldn't find anything. Please help!

Comment: Is there any reason you use this tag instead of the video one?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `<embed>` tag. Try using the `<video>` tag instead, along with this code snippet. You could also use an `<iframe>` with the `allowfullscreen` attribute set to "true", but I'll leave it out of this example. Note that trying to run this code snippet on Stack Overflow doesn't work, as there must be some feature blocking it, but it does work in this JSFiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/pa85umLo/. Another important note is that the Fullscreen API doesn't work across all browsers - especially not mobile browsers, as it is a new thing they are working on. One last important note is that the "Fullscreen" button I provided is only for backup if the toggle button on the video controls does not pop up; the toggle button was there in addition to my button when making the JSFiddle, but sometimes it doesn't pop up by default, like on SO as I said earlier. The CSS selector is designed for Chrome only.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <video id="video" width="490" height="276" controls>
    <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4">
    <p>
      Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
    </p>
  </video>
  </section>
  <button id="video-button">Fullscreen Video</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var requestFullscreen = function (element) {
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.log('Fullscreen API is not supported.');
    }
};

var fullscreenVideo = document.getElementById('video-button');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

fullscreenVideo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    requestFullscreen(video);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button { visibility: visible; }
```